# Testing In-app Promotions: how to cancel a purchase made with a promo code

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, promotions, in-app-promotions

Is there any way to cancel a purchase made with a promotion code?

The developer console shows the count of redeemed promo codes but I didn't find a way to administrate and cancel them.

According to the [Testing In-app Promotions documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_promotions.html#testing) there are 3 workflows to test. I have an in app purchase that is a non consumable product (no more ad) so there is no way in the app to buy it twice if I already have it.

So how to easily test these workflows on the same user account?

Comment: Got a solution? Yes, consuming does the trick, but that's not always the case. For example, canceling promo codes opened to the public too early by mistake, or codes that were stolen by someone, etc. We can end the promotion from the console, but can't do anything about those already used. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

However you can consume your purchase to cancel a promo code with

```
public int consumePurchase(int apiVersion, String packageName, String purchaseToken)
```

Comment: Thanks, it perfectly make sense. I didn't think about it because this in-app can't normally be consumed but, consumable or not, you can consume it to void it.

Answer (score 0):

There no place to cancel promo code purchases as of now. If you do a promo code purchase or test purchase, you can not cancel it, thus you can not buy a feature more than once.

Comment: Thanks but what is the workflow to test promotions? Do you have to create fake user account each time you want to test it? Sounds like a nightmare to test...

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could do 1 day duration promos. Is  it not the best solution but after cancelation you  old use the same user.

Comment: 1 day duration promo means you can use the promo only during 1 day, not that it will be canceled after 1 day.

Comment: Yes sure. But after that you are free to use a new promo with te same user. This solve the problem!!

Comment: The issue is not related to using new promo code but canceling the purchase. As it is related to a non consumable product, you can't buy it twice; you can't use several promo codes. Anyway the correct answer has been given: even for a non consumable product, you can consume it.